# Drag select time range in Reaper not working

Tags: reaper

I am using Reaper 3.75 and normally I click and drag in the time-bar at the top to select an area, but suddenly it is not working anymore. Have I activated some kind of strange mode, and how do I get out of it?

Comment: You probably enabled Locking by clicking the lock icon in the toolbar by accident.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check your Lock Settings for the project.  Press Shift+L (or right click the Locking icon in the toolbar) to open the dialog.

When I selected Enable Locking and Time Selection, I was unable to make a time selection by clicking and dragging in the Timeline.

Clicking the lock icon in the toolbar will toggle Locking.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar thing happen; When I moved the triangular things along the ruler at the top, suddenly the time selection wouldn't change (the ruler changed, but the highlighted area didn't move, nor did the selection time meter.

Solution for me was under Options, I had to check "Loop points linked to time selection"

Not sure how it got unchecked, but it was frying my egg for a couple days until I figured it out.

Just thought I'd throw it up there in case anyone else found this same page looking for solution.